# loading a class present in an external jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, ojdbc

I am loading a class using `class.forname` in my Java project which is packaged as runnable jar using Eclipse. The class I am loading is not present in the same jar.

My idea was that the jar containing the class to be loaded just needs to be in the Classpath. However that's not working and I am getting *class not found*.

To be specific I am loading Oracle driver class(`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`) using `class.forname` in my Java project, which I have packaged as a runnable jar from Eclipse. The runnable jar does not have the ojdbc jar included. I have kept the ojdbc.jar file containing the oracle driver class in my classpath and then I try to execute the runnable jar. It gives class not found. I have verified the classpath and it contains the jar. Even the class exists.

Is my understanding of how class.forname works wrong. Can't it load classes from jars in classpath? What needs to be done in that case? I don't want to include drivers in my package.

Comment: A runnable jar cannot have its classpath amended (if run with the `-jar` option). Any classpath settings other than in the manifest are ignored. You need to either bundle the Oracle jar into it as well, or point to it (by relative path, which is not too robust) from the Manifest.  Or start it without `-jar` (by passing classpath and main class instead).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So executing without -jar command means, I have to run the main class with java command and have both jars in classpath?

Comment: Yes. `java -cp one.jar:two.jar my.package.MainClass`

Comment: My jar packages other jars within it. While running as a Java program will references to these jars(classes) work or I need to pull out those from within the jar and keep them separately on classpath?

Comment: Depends on how it was packaged. Give it a try.